# How to change lookup hyperlink to open in another tab instead of a dialog in SP2013

Tags: lookup-column, hyperlink

Currently when I click on the accounting projects link:

[image: I click on the Accounting Projects link]

This dialog box opens:

[image: This dialog box opens]

Instead of a dialog box I want this page to open in a new tab:

[image: I want this page to open]

Any Ideas on how I can do this?

I tried using the following java script from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a241b61a-0b8b-4293-b059-a7d661eae78e/sharepoint-2010-change-lookup-hyperlink-to-open-in-same-window but it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td[class='ms-vb2'] a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick","");
   });
});
```

Comment: The list can be set to open in the standard list views versus opening in the modal, then you can just control click a link to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but a fairly easy workaround: If you open the view page for the item itself and *then* click on the lookup from within that ViewForm, it will open the lookup item ViewForm in a new tab.